# The sales and marketing cube cube either does not exist or has not been processed in AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, cube

I installed analysis services successfully and processed in SQL. But when I am opening Sales Analysis report below error is showing.

Error : the sales and marketing cube cube either does not exist or has not been processed

Can any one please suggest to resolve this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, _does_ the cube exist, and _has_ it been processed?

Comment: Thank you for reply underscore_d, yes its processed in SQL

Answer (score 2):

You have to [Grant users access to cubes](https://technet.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/aa570082.aspx) using SQL Server Management Studio or raw SQL.